# Using the Data Load Table in Oracle Apex for a table that I have access

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

Hi I am trying to use the Data Load Table in Oracle Apex for a table that I have access to through a different schema. For example I need to insert via CSV for table x which belongs in the schema X. However, I only have access to schema Y, which has access granted by schema Y. This mean I can access table x by querying, but whenever I try to choose the table for the Data Load table for schema Y, table x doesn't show up. Whenever I choose table x through schema X, it shows an error, which is because I don't have access to schema X. How can I select the table x through schema Y. I tried everything, and tried to edit the code looking through pages, but I can't find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have access to schema Y:

- connect to it
- create a synonym for user X's table X
- use that synonym in Apex

**[EDIT, a new approach, fooling Apex]**

- connect as Y
- `create table x as select * from x.x where 1 = 2`
- go to Apex, create the whole loading process which uses table X that belongs to user Y
- once it is done & tested, `drop table y.x`
- `create synonym x for x.x`

Apex will still think that it is a *table*, but it is a *synonym* instead.

Comment: I have been using synonym for table x. But the data loading wizard forces me to first select my schema through a drop down menu (gui). Then it loads a list of tables in that schema. This forces me to go to the table through the schema that it belongs in.

Comment: OK, so - fool Apex. Create a table which looks exactly like the "real" table: `create table x as select * from x.x where 1 = 2;`. Now you'll have the real table in schema Y, which will let you create the whole loading process. Once it is done, drop the table and create synonym.

Comment: What do you mean? drop the table and create synonym.

Comment: I edited my answer, have a look. It was simpler to do it that way, than writing another difficult-to-read comment.

Comment: Why don't you fix it? I'm not standing behind you and can't see what you have or what you do, apart from what you say. Users X and Y, tables X aren't very descriptive and it is easy to mess up things. If that object exists (which one? How could I know that?), either drop it, or create a new one using another name.

Comment: So there is schema X and schema Y. The table I need is table x which belongs to schema X and I only have access to schema Y. Currently, there is a synonym for table x under schema Y, so I can access table x if I query select * from from Y.x. However, my problem is that when I use the data load wizard tool on APEX, it forces me to choose the table that is within its schema, so I can't choose table x through schema Y because it doesn't show up. I can't choose table x through schema X because I have no access to it..